# Spring Framework @Cachable annotation and European Central Bank API JAVA

Tags: java, spring

I want to use Spring Framework @Cachable annotation and European Central Bank API from where i will get the rates agains EUR. I saw in spring docs that @Cachable annotation is used to cache some data which will be always the same... but is there a way to reload the method which caches the value for the rate (on every 5 hours maybe or...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use `@Scheduled`

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = "0 0 */5 * * *")
@CacheEvict(value = { CACHE_NAME })
public void clearCache() {      
}
```

The format of cron is

> second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday

Do not forget to add `@EnableScheduling` to your config

Comment: If i understand this... It will reload the cached data once in every 24 hours ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Now this cron will be executed every 5 hours

Comment: OK! Thanks. There was no need to edit this. I was just asking if i understand it write. :)